# Initializing member of type char * in function raises warning and gives unintended behaviour

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to make a function that will recieve a `const char *` variable to initialize a `char *` member of a structure and return said structure. The problem is I get a warning that says I'm casting a pointer to integer. Also, when I try to print, it doesn't work how I expected, though initializing outside the function works perfectly. I am using `gcc` with no flags to compile it. I made a minimal version of my code that gives me the same warning:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person {
    char name[128];
};

struct Person initialize_person(const char *name);

main() {
    /* raises warning: */
    struct Person person1;
    person1 = initialize_person("John Doe");

    /* does not raise a warning: */
    struct Person person2 = {"Mary Foo"};

    printf("person1: %s\n"  /* prints garbage */
           "person2: %s\n", /* prints what is expected */
           person1.name, person2.name);

    return 0;
}

struct Person initialize_person(const char *name)
{
    struct Person new_person = {name};
    /* I thought name would be equivalent to
       litterally "John Doe" here */

    return new_person;
}
```

And it raises this warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘initialize_person’:
main.c:25:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  struct Person new_person = {name};
         ^
main.c:25:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_person.name[0]’) [enabled by default]
```

Comment: **There is no `char *` member in your `struct`!** Please write 100 time: An array is not a pointer is not an array!

Comment: @Olaf, how come when I try `printf("%d", person.name)` I get the warning that `%d` expects `integer`, and not `char *`?

Comment: Because in **most** cases, an arra **decays** to a pointer. But that does **not** mean they are the same. This should be stated in every good C book! Or in the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Answer (score 3):

This really has nothing to do with the structure, but everything to do with the char array.

An initializer for `char[]` cannot be a pointer-to-char. It must be either string literal, or a sequence of values convertable to `char`.

(Looking for help with the actual formal definition, if anyone has it.)

In other words:

```
char foo[128] = "foo";
```

or

```
char foo[128] = {1, 2, 3};
```

The problem is that the compiler needs a constant expression to be there, so it can generate code that initializes the structure with those values. The key is that the *length* of either initializer is known.  With your code that tries to use a pointer, the length is not known.

A bit of advice before I give a solution: Don't pass structures by value to functions, and don't return them from functions either. Working with pointers to structures is much more efficient, because the structure doesn't need to be copied.

```
bool initialize_person(struct Person *person; const char *name)
{
    if (strlen(name) > sizeof(person->name - 1) {
        // Name is too long
        return false;
    }

    strcpy(person->name, name);
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Person person1;

    if (!initialize_person(&person1, "John Doe")) {
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the warning about the cast then? Where is the integer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given this declaration:

> ```
> struct Person {
>     char name[128];
> };
> ```

You cannot initialize a `struct Person` like so:

> ```
> struct Person initialize_person(const char *name)
> {
>     struct Person new_person = {name};
> ```

A string literal is not the same thing as a `char *` (`const`ness notwithstanding), in very much the same way that an array is not a pointer.  To initialize a `struct` member that is a `char` array from variable data, you need to explicitly copy.  This is about as close as you can get to what you seem to have intended:

```
    struct Person new_person;

    strncpy(new_person.name, name, sizeof(new_person.name) - 1);
```

Do note, however, that when you return that `struct` you will create *another* copy.  Consider instead either passing a pointer to the `struct` you want to initialize along with the initialization data, or dynamically allocating the `struct`, initializing it, and returning a pointer to the result.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the initializer for new_person.

```
struct Person new_person = {name};
```

It does not copy the array pointed by name to the array new_person.name
Instead it does this :

```
struct Person new_person; new_person.name[0] = name;
```

So it is trying to copy a pointer to a char, hence the warning.  `new_person.name[0]` gets a value different from what you want and the rest of the array remains uninitialized, hence garbage is printed.

An incorrect way of solving it would be :

```
struct Person new_person =  
{name[0],name[1],name[2],name[3],name[4],name[5],name[6],name[7],name[8]};
```

Your program will work fine like that. But only because "John Doe" and "Mary Foo" have at most 8 characters. It will fail with larger strings.
The proper way to solve it would be :

```
struct Person new_person;
sprintf(new_person.name, "%.127s", name);
```

That will work even with strings which don't fit in the space reserved to name. They will be cut and only the 127 first characters will be used.